# What are the advantages of using timeout property in Spring framework?

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, jta

When I read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vs-jta-transactional) tutorial about transaction, I notice `timeout` property, which I have never used before in any of REST services I have developed.

For example, in this code:

```
@Service
@Transactional(
  isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, 
  propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, 
  readOnly = false, 
  timeout = 30)
public class CarService {
 
    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;
 
    @Transactional(
      rollbackFor = IllegalArgumentException.class, 
      noRollbackFor = EntityExistsException.class,
      rollbackForClassName = "IllegalArgumentException", 
      noRollbackForClassName = "EntityExistsException")
    public Car save(Car car) {
        return carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

What is the benefit or advantage of using `timeout` property? is it a good practice to use it? can anyone tell me about use-cases of timeout property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One is to stop records being locked for long and unable to serve any other requests.
2. Let says you are booking a ticket. On the final submission page, it is talking so long and will your user wait forever? So you set http client time out. But now you have the http client time out, what happens if you don't have transaction time out? You displayed error to user saying it didn't succeed but your transaction takes it time as it does not have any timeout and commits after the your http client has timed out.

Comment: Thanks so it's a good idea to add timeout property or not ?

Comment: Yes. It is good idea to add it. But it shouldnt be too short or too long, deciding will be the difficult part. You can reserach on that.

Answer (score 3):

As [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) explain:

> *Timeout* enables client to control how long the transaction runs before timing out and being rolled back automatically by the
> underlying transaction infrastructure.

So, the benefit is evidently obvious - to control how long the transaction (and queries under that) may be lasting, until they're rolled back.

Q: Why controlling the transaction time is useful/good?

> A: If you are deliberately expecting your transaction not to take too long - it's a good time to use this configuration; if you're expecting that your transaction might take longer than its `default` maximum time, it is, agian, helpful to provide this configuration.

Comment: Hi @Giorgi Tsiklauri if the benefit is evidently obvious why use Timeout  is very rare in real world project

Comment: Because, it is a one more attribute for AOP to control and manage. If you're sure, that your transaction is unlikely to take long, or! if you are deliberately expecting your transaction not to take too long - it's a good time to use this configuration.

Comment: Can you plz explain more "one more attribute for AOP to control and manage"

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a look.. @Transactional is managed and handled by AOP facilities. If you don't understand it now, it's a bit difficult to explain everything here.. however, I think I provide enough information to see why using this can be good or bad.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above answers are correct, but something you should note is that:

> this property exclusively designed for use with `Propagation.REQUIRED`
> or `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` since it only applies to newly started
> transactions.

as documentations describes.